# Non-standard complex structure on $\mathbb R^{2n}$

Tags: lie-groups, almost-complex

First let me give some relevant information:

For every $n$ every subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_m(\mathbb R)$ for some $m$.

Let $\rho_n: M_n(\mathbb C) \hookrightarrow M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ be the map 
$$ \rho_1 (a + ib) = (\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ -b & a\end{array})$$
and similarly for $n>1$.

A real matrix $A \in M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ is called complex linear if it is in the image of $\rho_n$. Then there is the following theorem:

If $f_n:\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb R^{2n}$ denotes the map $(x_1 + y_1i, x_2 + y_2i, \dots) \mapsto (x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2, \dots)$  then a real matrix $A \in M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ is complex linear iff the map $F=f_n^{-1}Af_n$ is linear.

The text I'm reading goes on to define

$$ J_{2n}=\rho_n(i I)$$

and then states "...The matrix $J_{2n}$ is called the standard complex structure on $\mathbb R^{2n}$"

My goal is to, eventually, prove the theorem I posted above but before I can attack that I really need to see what's going on here. Even looking at $J_4$ I don't know what to make of this. To help me understand my question therefore is:

> If $J_{2n}$ is the standard complex structure, what would be a
>   non-standard complex structure?

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be an even-dimensional real vector space. An *(almost) complex structure* on $V$ is an endomorphism $\mathcal{J} : V \to V$ such that $\mathcal{J}\circ\mathcal{J} = -\operatorname{id}_V$.

If $V = \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, then with respect to the standard basis we have $\mathcal{J}(v) = Jv$ for some $J \in GL(2n, \mathbb{R})$. As $\mathcal{J}\circ\mathcal{J} = -\operatorname{id}_V$, $J^2 = -I$ where $I$ is the $2n\times 2n$ identity matrix. The form of the *standard (almost) complex structure* on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ depends on how $\rho_n$ is defined ("and similarly for $n > 1$" does not make it clear what $\rho_n$ is). Usually one takes

$$J_{2n} = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & -I\\
I & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix (although it seems, according to your conventions, you may want to swap $-I$ and $I$). Then a non-standard (almost) complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is given by a matrix $J \neq J_{2n}$ with $J^2 = -I$. For example, any matrix similar to $J_{2n}$ defines a non-standard (almost) complex structure.

**Explicit Example:** Let

$$J = \left[\begin{matrix} -3 & -5\\
2 & 3\end{matrix}\right],$$

then $J^2 = -I$, so $\mathcal{J}(v) = Jv$ is a non-standard (almost) complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

Note, what you've called a complex structure, I've called an almost complex structure. The reason I use the latter is that one can extend the notions above to even-dimensional manifolds where there is already a notion of complex structure. You may also see the phrase *linear complex structure*; for example, this is the terminology used on [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure).

Comment: Almost complex is a term used to mean a very specific thing in geometry and what you defined seems to only be complex. An almost complex structure is a section of $\operatorname{End}(TV)$ where its square is still $-I$. This distinction seems quite important as there are spaces with this kind of structure but no complex structure (i.e. conjecturally $S^6$). So in your case the $J$ should be a matrix valued function on $\Bbb R^{2n}, if that is really what you intended to define

Comment: @PVAL: You're viewing $V$ as the manifold which is not what I am doing. If you consider a $2n$-dimensional almost complex manifold $(M, J)$, what I am describing above is the map $J_x : T_xM \to T_xM$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $J_4 = \rho_2 (i I)$ was given as $$ \begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{array}$$
I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Does the homomorphism $\rho_n$ have a name?